# phpquery codeigniter howto

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpquery

Is there anyone that has a howto and tutorial on using phpQuery with CodeIgniter?

I ask because I would like to manipulate certain css attributes and swap out certain css values. I could have done this with JavaScript but it's tough mixing PHP and JavaScript, so it means finding a way to manipulate HTML and css to do this. Hope y'all can help in anyway.

so I am looking to load phpquery and use it like any other library

```
$this->load->libary('phpquery');
$this->phpquery->pq('div > p')->findall();
```

Answer (score 4):

I got phpQuery to work in my current CodeIgniter project by using the `onefile` version of phpQuery as a helper.

#### install

1. Download [phpQuery-onefile.zip](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/list)
2. Extract and copy phpQuery-onefile.php to `/your/ci/proj/application/helpers/phpQuery_helper.php`
3. Load it like a normal helper.

#### usage

Here's a very basic example that I have working.

```
//to load in a controller
$this->load->helper('phpQuery');

//I'm using phpQuery in one of my libraries. So, load like this..
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('phpQuery');

//now use phpQuery like normal.  
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML('<div id="test">This is a test.</div');

$testElement = pq('#test');

echo $testElement->html(); //This is a test.
```

#### alternatively

You could also just use a regular old `include_once('path/to/phpQuery-onefile.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried PHP's DomDocument class?

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

This should be of some use?